# how to search characters between parentheses and search for a named backreference regex python

Tags: python, regex, string, parentheses

i've this line

```
          15815 (sh): demand=3000000 boost=1 reason=0 sync=0 need_idle=0 flags=80002 grp=0 best_cpu=6 latency=0
```

i want to extract sh and flags value with named backreference using python regex, but always landing up with a None type object, how do i do that?

Below is code for what i tried:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\((?P<thread>.*?)\)*\sflags=(?P<flags>\d+)")


m = pattern.search(str)
 m.group()
'(sh): demand=3000000 boost=1 reason=0 sync=0 need_idle=0 flags=80002'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match any chars other than `(` and `)` to match what is inside `(...)` and then use `.*` or `.*?` to match up to the `flags`. Then, all you need is to use `group("thread")` and `group("flags")` to access these values:

```
import re
s ='          15815 (sh): demand=3000000 boost=1 reason=0 sync=0 need_idle=0 flags=80002 grp=0 best_cpu=6 latency=0'
pattern = re.compile(r"\((?P<thread>[^()]*)\).*?\bflags=(?P<flags>\d+)")
m = pattern.search(s)
print(m.group("thread")) # => sh
print(m.group("flags"))  # => 80002
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/DE2L0s)

Note I added a word boundary `\b` before `flags=` to match `flags` as a whole word.